# Error implementing LoaderManager

Tags: android

I implement LoaderManager Like this - 
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

But Eclipse says -'LoaderManager cannot be resolved to a type'
What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import classes that you reference in Java.

import android.app.LoaderManager;

If you're using an IDE like Android Studio or Eclipse, use Organize imports or press ctrl-space at the class name etc.